# JS Can't change value by index

Tags: javascript

I have this code:
const fs = require('fs');

const seats = fs.readFileSync('testData.txt').toString('utf-8').split('\n');

and when I do seats[1][1] = "G" for example, the value of seats[1][1] remains the same. Why is that and can it be changed?

Comment: Strings are immutable. `seats[1]` is a string, and `seats[1][1]` is the second character in that string.

Comment: Is there an easy way to change these values? Can I make a new object declared with var or something similar?

Comment: you could use .split("") to turn the string into an array of characters